# E/ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.default.sync')

Tags: android, react-native-code-push

add codePush into my project with Error:

```
E/ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.default.sync')
```

when I use a new react project with module app, install code push as the document says https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-android.md

everything is fine.

But When I add code push into my existing project, the module named "passenger", not "app", I follow the step with the document, add code push Manual.

also add code into `index.android.js`

```
import CodePush from "react-native-code-push";

componentDidMount(){
        console.log("CodePush");
        CodePush.sync();
    }
```

When I run my module, this error come across. `CodePush` undefined.
Is anybody know what wrong with it?

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? I've just faced same issue here.

Comment: yeah, I solved my problem.I add these code in my android project ;

Comment: just add the code as @cube says below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by add some line in my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("main.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("TingBadgeManager")
            .addPackage(new SQLitePluginPackage())
            .addPackage(new CodePush("xxx", getApplicationContext(), com.xxx.xxx.BuildConfig.DEBUG))       // register CodePush Plugin here
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(true)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "TingBadgeManager", null);
    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}
```

Key point is that if you create your RN in an Activity you should add CodePush with `addPackage` in mReactInstanceManager.
Hope this can help.

Issue related : https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/871